# Enable Nginx GitLab to display error

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have installed an omnibus GitLab package, and i try to configure it. Everytime i have a page "ERROR 500, Whoops, something went wrong on our end.". I don't have `root` access and looking at the log files is very compelling for my team and me.

Do you know if it's possible to definitively enable displaying errors directly in web page ? With a nginx command or a gitlab configuration var ?

I looked for a configuration variable in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file, but nothing found.

Comment: To install GitLab you likely required root. To debug 500 errors, you'll require root to look at logs for cause + modify config files to fix problem.

Comment: @DavidFavor only the administrator has root access, and he gives us specific rights (like yum commands for installation), but he can't give me read access on `/var/logs/gitlab` cause Gitlab have a log rotate which change folder rights everydays. That's why i search to display directly the error on web page